# What should my "my.conf" for mysql look like?

Tags: mysql, file, configuration, fiware-knowage

I'm trying to install knowage in a linux virtual machine. To install knowage I have to install mysql.

When I install mysql I get this typical error which I can't solve in any way I've found.

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    mysql-server-5.7
>    mysql-server

When I try the command service mysql -status, it tells me:

> Can't connect to local mysql server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock''

That directory doesn't exist so looking on the internet, I've found solutions by modifying the file my.conf, but that file looks nothing as examples of other people.

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

I don't know it this would solve my problem but it's giving me headache. The main problem is that I can't install knowage due to mysql installation error.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to to migrate to another database, Knowage has the option to support different types of databases? [Install Knowage-Server from release package](https://knowage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/README/index.html#installation-from-released-package)

On the other hand, if you dont like to change it read this page, it may help you. [how to install mariadb on debian 9](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-debian-9)